# cartItems array and localStorage not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making an e-commerce app using the MERN stack. I am using the Redux Toolkit library for state management. I have run into a problem:

1. The cart Items array is not getting updated with the payload.
2. When I am checking the local storage, it is showing an empty array.

What's wrong?

**cartSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
};

export const cartItemsAdded = (id, qty) =>
  createAsyncThunk("cart/cartItemsAdded", async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
    return {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    };
  });

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [cartItemsAdded.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      //cartItems array should be updated after the following line, but it is not getting updated with the payload.
      state.cartItems.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

**cartScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { cartItemsAdded } from "./cartSlice";

const CartScreen = ({ match, location }) => {
  const { id } = match.params;

  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);

  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(cartItemsAdded(id, qty)());
      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, qty, cartItems]);

  return <div>Cart</div>;
};

export default CartScreen;
```

Comment: I think the problem is dispatch(cartItemsAdded(id, qty)()) is async function, and localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems)) run before api response.

Comment: I put the localStorage("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItemsAdded(id, qty))) in the extraReducers field, after I update the cartItems array. Still, the localStorage is showing an empty array. I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createAsyncThunk` is wrong. Change it to this:

```
export const cartItemsAdded = createAsyncThunk("cart/cartItemsAdded", async ({ id, qty }) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
    return {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    };
  });
```

Edit: you'll also need to update this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(cartItemsAdded({ id, qty }));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, qty]);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Matt. I now understood the problem.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435276/redux-toolkit-unable-to-get-access-to-the-error-message-sent-from-the-server

Answer (score 0):

Here you are mutating the array itself, so reference will not change for the change detection

try changing this line to

```
state.cartItems.push(action.payload);
```

this

```
state.cartItems = [...state.cartItems, action.payload]
```

Comment: I changed as per your suggestion. But the cartItems array is still not getting updated.

Comment: They are using redux toolkit, which explicitly allows mutating the state. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this should be correctly updating the state, that does not mean it updates your `cartItems` variable.

On *next render*, there will be another variable in a new scope that is also named `cartItems` and that variable will contain the up-to-date cart items - but that old `cartItems` variable will not update.

So you will need to split up that `useEffect`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(cartItemsAdded(id, qty)());
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, qty]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartItems) {
      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    }
  }, [cartItems]);
```

Comment: I made the changes as per your suggestion, but the cartItems array is till not getting updated and the cartItems in localStorage is an empty array. When I check Redux dev tools, I have the action type: cart/cartItemsAdded/fulfilled. Also, I get the payload. but when I check the state, the cartItems array is still empty. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: stupid question: did you add the reducer from cartSlice to your store?

Comment: Yes. as follows:  export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
  preloadedState,
});

Comment: The preloadedState:                           const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

const preloadedState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
  },
};

Comment: Hm. That *looks* pretty okay. Without a runnable CodeSandbox, it is pretty impossible to get deeper into this. Without that I can only recommend you to first get it to work without any localStorage stuff and do that after. Maybe also look into redux-persist instead of doing that yourself.

Comment: Github repository: https://github.com/sundaray/Ecom_MERN, Can you pls. take a look? I will really appreciate your help. Thanks a ton.