# How to access backend errors with Redux createAsyncThunk

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am not sure how I am supposed to get the errors that come from the backend when a POST request is sent to the backend. If I use plain axios calls, I can simply get the errors from the response object in the catch block with:

```
error.response.data.errors
```

But when using Redux and using createAsyncThunk method, on a 400 status code from the server, a rejected action is dispatched and the error object I get is a generic one like so:

```
{
  message: "Request failed with status code 400"
  name: "Error"
  stack: "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n...."
}
```

How can I get the server errors, just like using axios?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the [rejectWithValue](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) function from redux-toolkit to include the server error as the payload property of your rejected action.

It would be something like this (untested code because I’m on my phone)

```
const myAction = createAsyncThunk(
  ‘actionName’,
  async ( arg, {rejectWithValue} ) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(…);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
       return rejectWithValue( error.response.data.errors );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is add an additional check for the errors and also wrap the axios post request with a try catch block.
Note : In your case the request is failing so I guess there must be some error with the way you are making a request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435276/redux-toolkit-unable-to-get-access-to-the-error-message-sent-from-the-server?rq=1

Comment: I did something similar to that.